# Jquery not working in modal popup ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a modal popup that I want to use some cascading drop down lists in.

The drop downs work fine when I render the page as a regular view but when I render it as a partial in a modal popup I lose the functionality.

The script doesn't seem to run at all now.

Here is the code that should run when a drop down value is selected:

```
$("#artistSelect").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#pieceSelect").empty();
    $("#productSelect").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMasterImages")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            artistId: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function (masterImages) {
            $(masterImages).each(function (i, masterImage) {
                $("#pieceSelect").append('<option value="' + masterImage.Value + '">' + masterImage.Text + '</option');
            });
            $("#productSelect").append('<option value="">-- Select Piece --</option>');
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('failed to get piece list.' + ex);
        }

    });
} else {

    $("#pieceSelect").empty();
    $("#productSelect").empty();
    $("#productSelect").append('<option value="">-- Select Artist --</option>');
    $("#pieceSelect").append('<option value="">-- Select Artist --</option>');
}
return false;
});

$("#pieceSelect").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $("#productSelect").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            imageMasterId: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function (products) {
            $(products).each(function (i, product) {
                $("#productSelect").append('<option value="' + product.Value + '">' + product.Text + '</option');
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('failed to get product list.' + ex);
        }
    });
} else {
    $("#productSelect").empty();
    $("#productSelect").append('<option value="">-- Select Piece --</option>');
}
return false;
});
```

The scripts are located in my main scripts file.

and my now partial view:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("Artist", Model.Dropdowns.ArtistItems, new { @id = "artistSelect", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("Piece", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Select Artist --", Value = "" } }, new { @id = "pieceSelect", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerItem.ItemID, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Select Artist --", Value = "" } }, new { @id = "productSelect", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Why do my cascading drop downs no longer work?

Comment: It's because your partial view is loaded after the jQuery Code is Executed. So the Change event is not binding with the dropdown.
  If you create a script tag in your partial View and place you jQuery in that tag it should work.

Comment: If you want to keep you script in the same file use event trigger. $('body').on('change', '#Artist', function(e){      // PUT YOUR CODE HERE       })

Comment: Thanks.  That got it working.  I previously had tried moving the scripts to the partial view file but I had placed them in an @section which caused them to no longer function.